# Android App Detect Other Activity

Tags: android, events, mobile, notifications, detect

I've been trying to look up solution but I just can't seem to find one that suits my need. It could be that I'm not using the correct keyword, so I'm gonna try to explain it the best I can.

Simply saying, I'm building an Android application. The application need to detect some other activities on the phone and show some message.

For example:

1. User launch MyApplication.
2. User received some notification from another app. (a phone call, text message, email, whatever)
3. MyApplication shows a message via toast or dialog, saying that "you just received an notification from another app"

I'm not entirely sure what function I should be looking for here, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "User received some notification from another app" -- do you literally mean [the Android SDK class `Notification`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: like when you are using an app and then you receive an email, a notification bar show up on the top of the screen (then you tap the bar to actually open the email app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look at [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html), this will let you receive calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

Once you receive a callback from the `NotificationListenerService`, you will want to create a [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Take a look at [this](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html) tutorial should help you get started.

Comment: No problem, please take a look at my revised answer. Thanks!

Comment: With the example, I was able to get my app to listen to "ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED", is there a way to listen to other actions as well?

Comment: I mean like I don't want to limit myself to a specific action, I want it to trigger every time a notification bar show up at the top of the screen

Comment: I misunderstood, please take a look at my updated post.

Comment: Ah yeah! That's more of what I'm looking for! I got that figured out and was able to create Toast! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To detect when other apps ask the OS to display a `Notification`, you would need to implement a `NotificationListenerService`. The user would then not only need to install your app, but also go into Settings and specifically allow you to monitor notifications.

Comment: Thanks! NotificationListenerService is what I was looking for and I got it to work in my program!